# Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected error in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to hadoop.
I'm writing a mapreduce code which converts text files to PDF but I'm getting the above error.
After searching the problem on web, I found that the problem is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext was a class in Hadoop 1 but became an interface in Hadoop 2. But, nowhere have I found how to solve this. Please help me with the problem.

Dependencies in my POM are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Don't mix hadoop-core version 1 with hadoop-common version 2. Decide on one version of Hadoop, and use only components from that version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Roland.I updated the dependencies to use Hadoop 1, but still I'm facing the same issue. Can you tell me the dependencies to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use the following hadoop related dependencies to avoid the "found interface but class expected" error:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```